# Deployment of Application

Tags: .net

I want to deploy my application to some other machine. I had build this application with Release version using .NET 3.5. What else is required to deploy this application, which will work on other machine which does not has .NET framework?

Comment: Please tell me whether to install .NET framework after creating a setup or .NET Deployment unit automatically adds this framework in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice [article](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3352511) for you to learn about deploying windows applications.

Comment: Your article has helped me in creating the package for it.Still i had one doubt that it includes .NET framework with this setup or still remote client needs to install .NET framework first???

Comment: "If you use setup.exe it will run a dependencies check and notify the user if they need a newer .NET framework or other library. Using the .msi will simply install without the check." NikeMrown's Answer. If .net is not found then the pc will try to download and install.

Comment: So if user doesnot have the .NET framework should i give the installer for that also?

Comment: NO this wil be taken care by the setup file

Comment: Ok thanks for ur response and really your article helps me lot.

Answer (score 2):

The other machine will need the .NET Framework one way or the other. You can bundle it with your installer, you can have your installer detect it and download and install it if necessary, or you can just ask your users to install the framework through Windows Update if they don't have it already.

Once the framework is on the machine, in the simplest case it's simply a matter of copying the contents of the bin\Release folder.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, add a "Setup Project" (under "Setup and Deployment" or "Other Projects Types") to your current solution. About the bare minimum would involve going to "File System" in the setup project and under the "Application Folder" you want to right-click and "Add Project Output."  Just select your application's release build.  It would be worth your time to read through the [MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235317.aspx) to familiarize yourself with the various options and settings. The setup project should detect your applications dependencies automatically (.NET, DLL's, etc)

Just to note, when you build your setup project you will get two installation options (Setup.exe and MySetupProject.msi).  If you use setup.exe it will run a dependencies check and notify the user if they need a newer .NET framework or other library.  Using the .msi will simply install without the check.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside; if you don't want to have to deploy the full framework; with 3.5 SP1 there is the [Client Profile](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx) - this is quite a bit smaller than the "full" 3.5 SP1, but omits a range of (usually-server-side) things like web and DAL classes.

IMO, it is easier to support the full framework, simply because it removes an extra variable...

Another option would be to develop the app as Silverlight; it may be too late for this, but Silverlight provides a very small client footprint (and easy install).

There are some programs that bootstrap the runtime into your code, but I don't recommend them.