# Installation Software for my VB.net programme

Tags: installation, vb.net-2010

In VB6 there was software to package and create setup files for my programme.

I sthere such a thing in VB.net / Visual Studio 2010?

I need to create a setup system with the EXE, lots of support files in seperate directories, and also an SQL Database.

What do people sugest?

Comment: I suggest searching here for `[.net] deployment` (with the brackets), as this has been asked many times before here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deployment of Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704086/deployment-of-application) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6704727

Answer (score 0):

```
For creating setup in visual studio, first create a windows application in visual studio 2010. For demonstration I have used one windows application. If you want to create same demo, then you read this article.

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/0ee20518-1858-4f57-b479-e651621d9584/?Creating%20setup%20in%20visual%20studio%202010
```